# Formik with two "master-slave" selects

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form with two selects.
Each of them is a react-select passed as a user-defined component to the Field component.

```
class _TaskForm {
...
<Field name={'project'} component={Select}>
<Field name={'task'} component={Select}>
...
}

const TaskForm = withFormik({...})(_TaskForm)
```

Now, I want to change a list of tasks when the project is changed.
The problem is: in project's onChange i receive only formik's {options, field, form} - none of them references _TaskForm.
I want to access it so I can update the options for the task select.

How can I access _TaskForm when the value of project changes?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean "access" _TaskForm ? Do you mean access one of its methods or properties inside the `Select` component?

Comment: @azium - yes, exactly. I need to change the list of options for the task select. I keep it as a property of the _TaskForm object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like you're just asking how to pass both Formik props and your own props to `Select`:

```
class TaskForm extends Component {
  state = { classProp: 'foo' }   
  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <Field 
        name={'project'} 
        component={formikProps => 
          <Select 
            {...formikProps}
            classProp={this.state.classProp}
          />
        } 
      />
      ...
    )
  }
}
```